# interp2(X, Y, Z, XI, YI) from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

I need the exact Python equivalent function of this [Matlab function](http://www.mathworks.it/help/techdoc/ref/interp2.html) in order to interpolate matrices.

In Matlab I have:

```
interp2(X, Y, Z, XI, YI)
```

while in Scipy I have:

```
interp2d(X, Y, Z).
```

In Scipy XI and YI are missing. How can I resolve this? I'm using all parameters in Matlab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is `ip = interp2d(x, y, z); zi = ip(xi, yi)`.

Also, `interp2d` is not exactly the same as `interp2`. [RectBivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html) is closer.

Comment: Hey pv, what function shall I use for closed curve or contour? RectBivariateSpline wanted the points to be in ascending order, which fails in case of contours.

Comment: @Gunjan did you get solution?

Comment: yes it is interp2d function

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue, and figured out that `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` does the same as `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)`. Please read the documentation of these commands to find out the solution for your case.

Try this for Matlab's `Vq = interp2(V,Xq,Yq)` :

```
Vq = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(V, [Xq.ravel(), Yq.ravel()], order=3, mode='nearest').reshape(V.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

for interp2(v,xq,yq)

```
ip = scipy.interpolate.griddata((y.ravel(),x.ravel()),distorted.ravel(),(yq.ravel(),xq.ravel()))
```

Note that the result returned needs to be resized. i.e ( `ip.resize(img.shape)`)

here `y,x` are

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(w),np.arange(h))
```

where `w,h` is the width and height of the image respectively.

For more you can read griddata documentation.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

> For interp2(X,Y,V,Xq,Yq), simply replace `x,y` with `X,Y`

Answer (score 0):

Interp2d outputs another function which allows you to call Xi and Yi.  However, watch out!  It evaluates them as a matrix, and not a scalar.  You will have to use a for loop to evaluate each pair of values for Xi and Yi individually and get the same behavior as MATLAB.

```
F=interpolate.interp2d(X,Y,Z)
Zi=[]
for i, j in zip(Xi,Yi)
   Zi.append(F(i,j))
```

Comment: is there another way, more direct, to get the vector instead of using the `for` loop?

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. You can get the diagonal of the `F(Xi,Yi)`, and you have the final vector.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to weigh in on this myself, as I was also struggling to find a Python equivalent of the MATLAB code:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y')
[XI, YI] = meshgrid(xi, yi')

Vq = interp2(X, Y, Z', XI, YI)
coeff = diag(Vq)'
```

where in *my specific case*, the MATLAB variables and sizes were,

- **x** & **y**: (m x 1) and (1 x n), respectively.
- **xi** & **yi**: both were (1 x w) size.
- **X** & **Y**: (m x n) mesh grids of my sample points.
- **Z**: (n x m) array of my corresponding function values (transposed in function).
- **XI** & **YI**: both were (w x w) mesh grids of my query points.
- **coeff**: (1 x w) array of the coefficients of interpolation.

I played around with scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline and was able to get the exact results produced by the MATLAB code. It was just a bit tricky as the documentation is a bit confusing, but the key is to use the .ev method. The Python code is as follows:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

# NOTE: The x, y, xi, and yi arrays are kept 1-dimensional, and not converted to meshgrids.

interp = RectBivariateSpline(x, y, Z, kx=1, ky=1)
coeff = interp.ev(xi, yi)
```

This code should give you the exact same results as the MATLAB code, where the sizes of my Python variables are as follows,

- **x** & **y**: (m,) and (n,), respectively.
- **Z**: (m x n), which is transposed from MATLAB.
- **xi** & **yi**: both variables are (w,) shape.
- **coeff**: (w,).